# Eclipse maven not using given user settings.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I set up a maven project in eclipse and because I'm behind a proxy, I gave the proxy settings in `D:\tools\....\settings.xml`. Eclipse is set up to use this path, when I click `Run as -> Maven Build ...` in eclipse, I see the correct path in the field "User Settings". But the debug output of maven tells me:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\...\settings.xml
```

consequently: no proxy,  ... Could not resolve dependencies ...

How can I convince maven to use my settings in `D:\...`?

Comment: "Maven > User Settings" in the Preferences

Comment: The correct location for your `settings.xml` is `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` (On Windows as far as I know `%HOME%\.m2\settings.xml` (default) will being picked up by Maven itself and by default also from Eclipse as well... or other IDE's also.

Comment: "Maven > User Settings" in the Preferences is set up to D:\... , that's why eclipse uses the D:\ path. I know, that  %HOME%\.m2\settings.xml is the default, but I want to use a path outside %HOME%

Comment: Why? Do you want to use a path outside `%HOME%` the settings.xml (can/should container credentials for accessing repos etc.)

Comment: The .m2 folder will also contain jars and it is not always desirable to have this in the profile path, because of size limitations.